# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

Yes I know another one (sorry) The error is on the line $statement = $pdo->prepare. I have another function pretty much similar to this one which uses the same details and that works. So am I missing something or....

```
/*DATA SQL ACCESS*/
$serverNetwork = "REDACTED";
$username = "REDACTED";
$server = "REDACTED";
$password = "REDACTED";
$pdo = new PDO($server,$username,$password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

function removeResultFromDB($userID, $term){
  global $pdo;
  try{
      $statement = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM `ValidSearchResults` WHERE  userID = ? AND searchTerm = ?");
      $statemtnt->execute([$userID, $term]);
  } catch (PDOException $e){
     $statement->error = $e->getMessage();
    var_dump($e);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't use globals. It is bad coding practice. Also can you show how you're calling `removeResultFromDB` ?

Comment: Just a wild guess: Do you include this code from "within" a function/method?

Comment: Could you paste the precise error?

Comment: @apokryfos in a file called previousSearches.php The user presses this link <p><a href="previousSearches.php?remove=<?=$value->searchTerm?>">Remove result</a></p>. A file called controller.php which is required_once in previousSearches.php then runs this code it gets a bit messy so here's a pastebin of the relevant parts of that file http://pastebin.com/27D4DpAr

Comment: @Julie Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /controller.php on line xxx

Comment: @volkerK I don't believe so no. Check the pastebin.

Comment: @GideonSassoon your pasted code seems to be calling `removeResultFromDB` before $pdo is defined (a valid reason as to why globals are bad practice).

Comment: Question, instead of  Globals what would you recommend?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Comment: Yeah moved the function call below the pdo declaration. In addition to the same error I also get: `Notice: Undefined variable: statemtnt in /controller.php on line (The same line)`

Comment: @GideonSassoon can you move the whole $pdo definition and credentials into the try/catch temporarily and see what errors (if any) you get?

Comment: I can but it would be copying, note that there are several more functions than besides this one which rely on the credentials (those do work)